# Issue with Stellar Quickstart Docker Image

Tags: horizon, docker

I'm trying to run the docker stellar/quickstart image. I launch it with:

`docker run -d -p "8000:8000" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --testnet`

I've left it running for quite some time but it never seems to connect to the network.

I checked the logs (`/var/log/supervisor/horizon-stdout---supervisor-0LqSDF.log`) and I'm seeing one error repeat itself:

```
time="2018-01-30T22:09:21Z" level=info msg="history db is empty, starting ingestion from ledger 0" pid=147
time="2018-01-30T22:09:21Z" level=error msg="import session failed: failed to load header: sql: no rows in result set" pid=147
```

Am I missing arguments? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: It seems to work when I remove the image and do a fresh download. But if I run `docker rm -f <containerId>` and launch a new container, that new container does not connect.

Comment: I use the following command (with xxx replaced with a real directory). 
 With this command you can look at 'localhost:11626/info' for some more details:  docker run -d --rm -it -p "8000:8000" -p "11626:11626" -p "11625:11625" -v "/xxx/xxx/xxx:/opt/stellar" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --pubnet

Comment: Have you tried running it in `-it` mode? Or perhaps try and actually mount the instance with the `-v` command in `-it` mode. I've had some issues previously running undocked ephemeral instances.

Comment: Also what does `docker -v` produce and what OS are you running on?

Comment: Docker version 17.06.0 running on macOS Sierra. I've tried `-it` and `-v` . Only thing that seems to work is deleting the image between each container launched.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using the latest image available? It's possible that your image is cached on your disk while a new version is available in docker repository. Try this to remove the image:

```
docker rmi -f stellar/quickstart:latest
```

and then run your the container using a standard command.

Comment: When the image is outdated you can simply do `docker pull stellar/quickstart:latest` to fetch the **latest** version. You can see on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/stellar/quickstart/builds/) when it was updated the last time:

Comment: @Bartek Nowotarski I've narrowed down the issue. It happens when I don't prune the image between containers. If I don't have the image locally I can run the command and it will connect. However if I run `docker rm -f <containerId>` and I run the `docker run` command again, it never connects to the network. Any idea why that would be? That might be more of a docker issue.